# Unable to perform POST request using jQuery to obtain Strava OAuth token

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, oauth, cors

I'm encountering an issue while trying to retrieve an access token using the Strava API: https://strava.github.io/api/v3/oauth/

My initial code request and callback function properly, but when attempting to hit the `/oauth/token` URL I fail in two different ways. The first:

```
        console.log('Posting to /token with code: ' + code);
        Ember.$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'https://www.strava.com/oauth/token',
            data: 'client_id=<myid>&client_secret=<mysecret>&code=' + code,
            success: function(data) {
                var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
                var accessToken = jsonData.access_token;
                console.log('Received access token: ' + accessToken);
                if (accessToken) {
                    this.get("controllers.application").set('settings.strava.accessKey', accessToken);
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                console.log('API auth error occurred: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
                throw new Error(error);
            }
        });
```

Prints `Posting to /token with code: 3ae248f...` and the HTTP request comes back with a 200 response (in the Chrome debugger Network tab), but I can't actually *see* the response contents/data in the debugger, and the browser console complains with:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.strava.com/oauth/token. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

But then if I add a few options to my above request:

```
        crossDomain: true,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'DELETE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS, POST, PUT',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
        },
```

Then an `OPTIONS` request goes out first (to the `/oauth/token` endpoint), and comes back with `302 Found`, but I then see a *different* error in the browser console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.strava.com/oauth/token. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

CORS is not something I have a *huge* amount of experience with, this is where I have run out of ideas.

Comment: It looks like CORS isn't supported here. You have to do this server side

Comment: I'm using the Strava API - I don't control this server. And the API has been around (and in use) for a while, so *I'm* doing something wrong.

Comment: It's not my server. It's a third-party server that I am connecting to.

Comment: You have to make the request from your server to the api server

Comment: Right - so my question is, what do I need to do to connect to this API?

Answer (score 1):

The following works fine in my Cordova App:

```
var c_id = "YOUR_ID_HERE";
var c_secret = "YOUR_SECRET_HERE";
var access_code = "YOUR_AUTH_HTTP_CODE_HERE";
var params = "client_id=" + c_id + "&client_secret=" + c_secret + "&code=" + access_code;

xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
  }
}

xmlhttp.open("POST", "https://www.strava.com/oauth/token", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xmlhttp.send(params);
```

Comment: Can we send logout request to strava??

Comment: Not that I am aware of. But you can "forget" the token on your app's side and re-authorize as per the first time authorization.

Comment: What I want to do is I want to log a user out from both my app and strava when he logs out from my app.Can this be done?

Comment: Nope - not that I am aware of.

Answer (score -2):

For the preflight requests response should ends up with status 200 Ok and contains at least `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: your origin`

Comment: How is this different from the wildcard origin I'm currently using? `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',`

Comment: You should get it in your response not send in your request, it hasn't meaning.

Comment: @CraigOtis, Has your web site backend app?

Comment: It's not a website - it's an EmberJS application that is running locally, and using jQuery to poll the Strava API.

Comment: Ok, I will ask in other manner. Does this code run in browser?

Comment: Yes, it runs in a browser.

Comment: Your approach is wrong. At first, including `secret` in JS code is a big security hole. Then, as I understand, `www.strava.com` doesn't allow `CORS`. You should have code running in your server which will perform authentication / authorization and where your `secret` will be safe.